# How to use joins to output a value associated with a value of the other table?

Tags: mysql, join

I have a quick question:
I have created the following tables:

```
create table playerdata (
id INT(100) NOT NULL auto_increment,
uuid CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
playername VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
coins INT(100) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(id, uuid, playername)
);

create table chunks (
id INT(100) NOT NULL auto_increment,
playerid INT(100) NOT NULL,
chunkid VARCHAR(50),
PRIMARY KEY(id, chunkid),
FOREIGN KEY(playerid) REFERENCES playerdata(id)
);
```

now I would like to try to output these with a join in such a way that a value from the column "chunkid" is output to a specified value from the column playername. But if I for example enter the following statement:

```
Select playername 
from playerdata, chunks 
WHERE chunkid = '13.4';
```

all saved player names are always output to me.

> Does anyone know how I can do this exactly?

me Thanks in advance

---

Okay. So I have already merged these two tables.

[The Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wf2yt.png)

For the output I would like that to e.g. the chunkid "13.4" then the player name (in the case "StraussFalke") is output. For this I have linked the left column "id" and the column "playerid" with a foreign key.

Comment: What you have there is a cross joins use and explicit join instead..https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html and what is the relationship between the 2 tables?

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the database how the tables are linked so that the player IDs of each table correspond to the others.

As as side note, to keep things more managable, you should give your tables an alias (a shortened name) and always use the names so that the database and you can keep track of which table each field references. Here I will use `pd` for the `playerdata` table and `c` for the `chunks` table.

```sql
Select pd.playername 
from playerdata pd, chunks c
where pd.id = c.playerid AND c.chunkid = '13.4';
```

The expression `pd.id = c.playerid` lets the database know you want to keep the player id field between the tables linked. Leaving that expression out, the database will just dump all the data from `playerdata` and any data in the `chunks` table where the `chunkid` field is 13.4 in the default order... but nobody will know if the data from one table is actually associated with the data from the other table - yikes!

The query above is equivalent to this query with a join expression:

```sql
Select pd.playername 
from playerdata pd
join chunks c ON pd.id = c.playerid
where c.chunkid = '13.4';
```

They will both return the same result.